# Add to a vector from another object to the object that created the object

Tags: c++

The main contains a vector. It creates a Foo foo object;
then foo's constructor adds 1 to the vector in main. How can this be done?

foo.cpp

```
foo::foo()
{
  mainvector.push_back(1);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> mainvector;
  Foo foo;

  return 0;
}
```

I cant seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Are you asking how you can get this to work or why it works? This can be made to work but it's terrible style.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. I want to be able to create an object and to have that object add 1 to the vector declared in the main.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.

Assuming this is how foo.h looks like:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(std::vector<int> & vec) {
            vec.push_back(<something>);
        }
}
```

This could be your main:

```
std::vector<int> mainvec;
Foo foo(mainvec);
```